# I found a Graph that defies the answer to this question...

Tags: graph-theory

I have this problem from graph theory which I am not entirely convinced with...

I am asked if there is a graph with six vertices with degrees {2,2,2,4,5,5}.
Answer, is apparently NO.

My question is...is there a rule to the order in which the degrees are presented?
like say, if the graph is presented to have degree {a,b,c} then does vertices with degree a and degree b have to be adjacent because they are presented next to each other in the set??

Because if not....I found a counter example and my answer to the question is YES there is.[image: I think this gives graph with 6 vertices and the required degree]

I am not asked for a simple graph or anything so the multiple edges from one vertex to another is allowed, yes?

I cannot find a reason to negate my example as a proof of existence for such a graph. The answer reasons with the sum of degrees being 20 which is twice the number of edges i.e. there are 10 edges, and if we let $v_1,v_2$ have degree 5 each, we come to the conclusion that it is impossible to construct such a graph.

Am I misunderstanding the notation of {2,2,2,4,5,5} here?? I don't see the rules...it would be great if someone can tell me why my example is not valid. Thanks!

Comment: We usually assume that graphs are simple, unless otherwise stated.  That is, graphs without multi-edges.  Your graph has vertices with 3 edges.  I suppose the non-existence result relates to simple graphs.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite common to just say "graph" and *implicitly* assume that the graph has no multiple edges. This usage goes together with the word "multigraph" to describe a graph that *may* have multiple edges.

The terminology "simple graph" is also available to specify this, but is more often used in context where it is *already* established that multiple edges are a relevant possibilities.

Apparently, the source you have for the claim that $(2,2,2,4,5,5)$ is not a possible degree sequence for a graph must be using the "multigraph/graph" terminology rather than the "graph/simple graph" terminology. That's all there is to it -- merely a difference in terminology.

When multiple edges are allowed, *every* finite sequence of nonnegative integers whose sum is even (and which doesn't contain a number that is larger than half the sum, unless you also allow loops) is a possible degree sequence. Since this makes the problem almost trivial, it is usually considered in the context where multiple edges are *not* allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The notation {2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5} is the [degree sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of the graph and is often written in descending order like : [5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2]. The [Havel-Hakimi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) gives an easy way to check if a sequence is 'graphical' (makes a graph). Conceptually, you take the highest degree **d** in the sequence and take one from the **d** next highest degrees. This is done repeatedly until either a) you get a sequence of zeros, b) you start getting negative values or c) you don't have enough to connect to.

So in your case, we have 5 as the largest value, so we take one from the next 5 degrees, leaving us with [0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1]. We repeat with 4 to get [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0] - which is where we stop. Note that this procedure does not guarantee a connected graph, nor does it give you all possible graphs with the supplied degree sequence.